# History of $ e^3\approx 20$

Tags: mathematics, calculus

Let $ e $ be the base of natural logarithms. Then $ e^3 = 20.08\dots\approx 20$. Was this convenient fact for back of the envelope calculations noted in the literature or in the historical record, and if so how early could it have appeared?

Comment: Is there any reason you suspect this approximation to have been of any historical significance at all?

Comment: @Danu not really, except that it's a useful way to approximate, especially when combined with $2^{10}\approx 10^3$.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Same goes for $2^3 \approx 3^2$

Answer (score 3):

I don't recall seeing this pointed out in 1800s literature, and I've looked at a HUGE amount of it in the past 10 years or so (over 1000 books, all volumes of over 15 journals). At least, if it was pointed out, it was only as a curiosity. Also, if you think about it, there is little use for this approximation. Unless you want rough approximations to constants times $e^{3},$ constants times $e^{6},$ constants times $e^{-3},$ etc. and their sums/differences, it won't help much. Unlike the case with $2^{10} \approx 10^{3},$ which is useful because *positive integer powers* of $2$ are what show up in practice (e.g., $23$ doublings is equivalent to multiplication by $2^{23} = 2^3 \times 2^{20} \approx 8 \times 10^{6}),$ the exponents that show up for base $e$ tend to be non-integers (because of the prevalence of functions involving exponentiating with base $e).$ Thus, I don't see how knowing $e^3 \approx 20$ is of much help in getting quick estimates (with around 5% accuracy) for things like $e^{2/3},$ $\;e^{1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4},$ $\;e^{-2.34},$ etc.

Comment: How about approximating $ e^{2000} $

Comment: Since $2000$ is not divisible by $3,$ I don't see how $e^{3} \approx 20$ would be of much use.

Comment: $ e^{2000}=e^{2001}/e=(e^3)^{667}/e\approx 2^{667}10^{667} $ for starters

Comment: It looks like you lost a factor of $e,$ and so $2^{667}10^{667}$ is about 60% less than $e^{2000}.$ Or am I overlooking something? Anyway, I think people in the past would simply use logarithm tables to get an approximation. In fact, there are lengthy books of tables of the exponential function that one would consult if numerical values of base-$e$ exponentiations were frequently needed. Nonetheless, it is interesting how these two approximations seem to want to work together.

Comment: I only meant very roughly, after all $ e^3> 20$ too